# Question put on hold as too broad

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I don't want to be that guy who complains about a rightful disciplinary action against him. But I really don't know what I did wrong here. I asked a question about a problem I'm currently encountering and tried to be as specific as possible. I have indeed provided every details I know (which is, admittedly, not very much) and nobody asked for more details in the comments. If it is rightfully put on hold I'd at least like to know why.

So here's [my question](https://superuser.com/q/1398880/711025):

> I have my keyboard plugged in in my monitor, which is not only
>   connected via Displayport, but also USB type B so that I can use a
>   bunch of USB ports of this monitor. This worked fine for a  while, but
>   since yesterday after booting my keyboard isn't detected anymore. Its
>   lights are still on, so it does get power, but my computer doesn't
>   recognize the inputs. This also doesn't change after I've logged in
>   (via the On-screen keyboard). Weirdly enough the other ports of my
>   monitor seem to work fine. As a workaround I can switch the port of my
>   keyboard with another device of my monitor and then both devices work
>   - until the next reboot, which forces me to switch them back again.
>
> Here are a few information regarding my setup:
>
> - Monitor: DELL U2515H
> - Keyboard: Lioncast LK 30
> - OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134 Build 17134)
>
> If you need more information, let me know in the comments.

I do agree of course that this doesn't very accurately describe a specific problem, but I simply don't know how to gather more information - as nobody commented anything on the post.

Comment: This isn't a disciplinary action, it's housekeeping.  Questions need to be answerable and as-is, and this one isn't.  "Too broad" refers to too many possible causes.  Typically, USB ports on monitors are for monitor input, they aren't pass-throughs to the computer.  I'm surprised it ever worked at all.  Hopefully, someone will suggest diagnostics you can run that might enable you to add sufficient information to make the question answerable.

Comment: @fixer1234 - It is not uncommon for Dell monitors to have a USB hub built into them, and for that to work, you must obviously connect the HUB to the computer.  When I have experienced similar problems, it's always been a USB power issue, or caused by the cable itself.